# SQL Server query that takes time

Tags: sql-server

For a recent test, I want to 'create' a query which takes atleast 5 seconds to execute and does not change the schema or data of the database - although I can create a table and then delete it. Till that level its ok . How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664902/sleep-command-in-t-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WAITFOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) command:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
```

Comment: any quick query that you can think of to run with the command?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If you just want output, you could do something like "SELECT 1 AS Test;"