# How could i limit and slow down my local SQL Express for test purpose?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado

I'm making a query in c# with ADO to select one record from Microsoft SQL Express database. for some test purpose I need to make a delay about 300ms with in SQL Express so that I could simulate my required situation.
There is a limitations that I can not use any store procedures.

Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could possibly inject a WAITFOR into your SQL:

See this SO QA for more info [Sleep Command in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664902/sleep-command-in-t-sql)

Given a command sent to the database:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable`

Embedded in a `SqlCommand`:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Change it to something like this:

```
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand("", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
#if DEBUG
        comm.CommandText = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000'; SELECT * FROM MyTable";
#else
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
#endif
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

To embed a 1 second wait.

Ideally you don't want to do this in such an ugly and questionable way, but for the purposes of demonstration it will suffice.

Comment: Are you sure that i could use this without getting involved with Store Procedures in SQL, cues as i mentioned using SP is a limitation.

Comment: At some point you are sending SQL commands to the database, likely straight from code.  In debug mode, add some conditional code that also injects a WAITFOR command - stored procedures aren't a requirement for it.

Comment: @Ehsan: Just run `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.300'; SELECT ... ;`

Comment: I'm relay stuck with this, have no idea how to join my select command with the WAITFOR in one T-SQL command !! I think I need more Help.

Comment: Thanks ypercube. That was great.

Comment: @Eshan I've provided an example, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could include a [`WAITFOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) command in your SQL batch.

Or, you could add a lot of data, and query over non-indexed columns, that's sure to make it slow.