# How to wait for 2 seconds?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How does one cause a delay in execution for a specified number of seconds?

This doesn't do it:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:02';
```

What is the correct format?

Comment: The thread seems to be waiting much longer than 2 seconds. I realize that it may take longer than 2 seconds for the thread to continue, but it is taking around 1 min when running on a local db that opnly I am using and have no other activity going.

Comment: This will actually wait exactly 2 minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep Command in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664902/sleep-command-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 513, accepted):

[The documentation for `WAITFOR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) doesn't explicitly lay out the required string format.

This will wait for 2 seconds:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
```

The format is `hh:mi:ss.mmm`.

Answer (score 162):

As mentioned in other answers, all of the following will work for the standard string-based syntax.

```
WAITFOR DELAY '02:00' --Two hours
WAITFOR DELAY '00:02' --Two minutes
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02' --Two seconds
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.200' --Two tenths of a seconds
```

There is also an alternative method of passing it a `DATETIME` value. You might think I'm confusing this with `WAITFOR TIME`, but it also works for `WAITFOR DELAY`.

**Considerations for passing `DATETIME`:**

- It must be passed as a variable, so it isn't a nice one-liner anymore.
- The delay is measured as the time since the Epoch (`'1900-01-01'`).
- For situations that require a variable amount of delay, it is much easier to manipulate a `DATETIME` than to properly format a `VARCHAR`.

**How to wait for 2 seconds:**

```
--Example 1
DECLARE @Delay1 DATETIME
SELECT @Delay1 = '1900-01-01 00:00:02.000'
WAITFOR DELAY @Delay1

--Example 2
DECLARE @Delay2 DATETIME
SELECT @Delay2 = dateadd(SECOND, 2, convert(DATETIME, 0))
WAITFOR DELAY @Delay2
```

**A note on waiting for `TIME` vs `DELAY`:**

Have you ever noticed that if you accidentally pass `WAITFOR TIME` a date that already passed, even by just a second, it will never return? Check it out:

```
--Example 3
DECLARE @Time1 DATETIME
SELECT @Time1 = getdate()
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
WAITFOR TIME @Time1 --WILL HANG FOREVER
```

Unfortunately, `WAITFOR DELAY` will do the same thing if you pass it a negative `DATETIME` value (yes, that's a thing).

```
--Example 4
DECLARE @Delay3 DATETIME
SELECT @Delay3 = dateadd(SECOND, -1, convert(DATETIME, 0))
WAITFOR DELAY @Delay3 --WILL HANG FOREVER
```

However, I would still recommend using `WAITFOR DELAY` over a static time because you can always confirm your delay is positive and it will stay that way for however long it takes your code to reach the `WAITFOR` statement.

Answer (score 31):

How about this?

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
```

If you have "00:02" it's interpreting that as Hours:Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
exec DBMS_LOCK.sleep(5);
```

This is the whole script:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "Start Date / Time" FROM DUAL;

exec DBMS_LOCK.sleep(5);

SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "End Date / Time" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Sorry. which flavour of SQL is this?

Comment: Looks like Oracle, based on a quick Google search for "DBMS_LOCK.sleep".