# Will executing Stored Procedure with Output Parameter wait till it finishes executing?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure. In SQL SERVER

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
    @Test
AS
BEGIN
    // Inside It, I am calling another SP with OUTPUT PARAM
  exec B
    @ErrorCode = @error output


-- SP B Will Return error if there is any in the logic

-- HERE I am checking 

IF(@error>0)
        UPDATE [dbo].[C] 
        SET IS_DELETED = 0,
        WHERE Id = 7

END
```

Is there any possibility that the update statement happens before @error is set ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps SQLServer?)

Comment: I believe your IF is supposed to be inside the Test SP (it's currently outside the BEGIN/END). Or the IF is the B SP?

Comment: You do not regain control until the inner stored procedure has completely finished executing. If you've got some unexplained behaviour, perhaps ask a direct question about that?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I got some unexplained behaviour.

Comment: @EzLo YOu are right.

Comment: Right, so change your question. You've got some unexplained behaviour. You thought one possible explanation could be if the code after `EXEC` can execute before that `EXEC` has finished. It cannot. So, tell us *what you expected to happen* and *what you're observing*.

Comment: No Way the if condition logic gets executed before that EXE ?

Comment: Can I Put wait statement ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676164/how-to-wait-for-2-seconds

Comment: NO. I've said as much twice already in the comments. Whatever's happening, it's *not that*. We can't help you though if you keep saying "it must be that" and seeking confirmation.

Comment: OK. @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there any way in which I can get all the queries executed against row, I am doubting somebody accessed the database and changed the value.